# convert list of class objects into json in python or django

Tags: python

```
my_objects = []
my_objects.append(Needed("bye",9))
my_objects.append(Needed("tata",8))
my_objects.append(Needed("hi",10))
```

i have list of object(example 5 objects in list) like this

```
class Needed:

   def __init__(self, name, number):
      self.name = name
      self.number = number
```

and i need to convert this into json order by count like below

```
{
   "results":[
               { "name":"hi",
                 "number":"10"
                },
                { "name":"bye",
                 "number":"9"
                },
                { "name":"tata",
                 "number":"8"
                },
                ...........
                ...........
              ]
}
```

so how to achieve this in django

Comment: This is not Django-related in any way.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers in django i do not have model and serializer so i have to like this only or otherwise i need to write my own annotate function to return number of count based on big logic, so i prefer this the way, can you give the some solution please

Comment: This is still not Django-related in any way - you have plain Python objects, the fact it's part of a Django project is totally irrelevant here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to make your objects json-serializable. You could provide a `default` encoder function or write your own `JSONEncoder` [as mentionned in the FineManual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), but for a simple one-off case like your example building dicts from your objects is probably the simplest solution:

```
class Needed(object):

   def __init__(self, name, number):
      self.name = name
      self.number = number

  def to_dict(self):
      return {"name": self.name, "number": self.number}
```

Then build a list of dicts from your objects:

```
results = [obj.to_dict() for obj in my_objects]
```

sort it based on `number`:

```
results.sort(key=lambda obj: obj["number"])
```

and serialize the whole thing:

```
jsdata = json.dumps({"results": results})
```

This is pretty ordinary Python stuff - building dictionaries out of objects, making a list of them and sorting the list.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that this is not django related, here is some Python code that can help you:

```
from operator import attrgetter

# sort objects by attribute number in reverse order
result = {'results': [obj.__dict__ for obj in sorted(my_objects, key=attrgetter('number'), reverse=True)]}

# `indent=4` returns a json string "prettyfied"
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Which prints:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "hi",
            "number": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "bye",
            "number": 9
        },
        {
            "name": "tata",
            "number": 8
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would not use `obj.__dict__` - it's ok for the given toy example but in real life it might expose attributes you don't want to be part of the result (and / or that might not be JSON-serializable).

Comment: Yeah, It was just for this purpose. You are absolutely right, though.

There should be a method that grabs the internal attributes dictionary and just returns the ones of interest.